# Cypress testing - compare token from localStorage to token stored in clipboard

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I have a button that copies the token from localStorage to the clipboard and I want to compare the token from localStorage to the token in clipboard to check if the token was copied correctly.

My code:

```
cy.get('.copy-to-clipboard').click();
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard').invoke('readText')
  .should('equal', localStorage.getItem(accessTokenKey));
```

It's my only idea and it's bugging and not comparing correct values.

Comment: What values does it compare then? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cypress doesn't have native copy/paste support yet, but there are some workarounds like:

**1. First Suggestion**

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
        expect(text).to.eq('your copied text');
    });
});
```

**2. Second Suggestion:**

```
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
  .invoke('readText').should('equal', 'copied text')
```

**3. Third suggestion, use dependence clipboardy**

First, install the dependence: `npm i -D clipboardy``

In your plugins/index.js file put:

```
const clipboardy = require('clipboardy');
module.exports = ( on ) => {
    on('task', {
        getClipboard () {
            return clipboardy.readSync();
        }
    });
};
```

Then use in your test:
`cy.task('getClipboard').should('contain', 'test');`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the mixture of sync and async code is the problem.

To fix try

```js
cy.get('.copy-to-clipboard')
  .click()
  .then(() => {  // defer until click finishes
    cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard').invoke('readText')  
      .should('equal', localStorage.getItem(accessTokenKey))
  })
```

or to make the `.should()` retry

```js
cy.get('.copy-to-clipboard').click()

const accessTokenKey = localStorage.getItem(accessTokenKey)
cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.wrap(win.navigator.clipboard.readText())  // on retry repeat readText
    .should('equal', accessTokenKey)
})
```